# What is the expected probability of a basket to be frequent on average?

Tags: probability

I was reading on frequent pattern mining algorithm and came up with the following question. Let a company have 10,000 different products and there are 1,000,000,000 transactions each containing exactly 10 different products. If for each basket a product is uniformly chosen, then what is the probability that a given fixed basket of size 10 is chosen for 1,000 times among 1,000,000,000 transactions?

This is self study and the problem is stated in Slide 9 in [here](http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/bk3/bk3_slides/06FPBasic.ppt)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in probability theory, but I think that the chance is practically 0. To see why, imagine you have a box with all possible baskets. Let `B` be the cardinality of the box, so the probability that one specific basket is drawn from the box is `p = 1/B`, approximately `p = 10^(-40)`. Imagine you draw `N` times from this box with replacement. Then you would expect that this specific basket would be drawn `m = N/B times`. This is the **expected frequency** of the experiment.

The standard deviation of this sampling process (`N` draws with probability of success `p`) is `σ = sqrt(N*p*(1-p))`. If you do the math with `N = 10^9`, `p = 10^(-40)` you find `σ = sqrt(10^(-31))`.

Suppose now that the **observed frequency** of the experiment is `f = 10^3`. Since the expected frequency is `m = N/B = 10^9/10^40 = 10^(-31)`, it follows that the `z-score` of this experiment is

```
z = (f-m)/σ = sqrt(10)*10^17
```

The chance of observing at least `f` instances of the specific basket is given by the normal approximation as the area under the standard normal curve between `z` and infinity. This area is practically zero.